# How to replace every instance of a string in a $http json response

Tags: angularjs, json, http, angularjs-ng-repeat

CODEPEN here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGeNLK

I have a $http response like the following.

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',  
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/itemsSite/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('items')/items?$select=*",
        cache: true,
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.items = data.d.results;          

    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

    });
```

The results, of which there are usually between 50 and 100, look **somewhat** like this

```
      {
    name: 'Item One',
    desc: "Item 1 [ITEM:1]View 1[/ITEM] Item 1b [ITEM:1b]View 1b[/ITEM] Item 1c [ITEM:1c]View 1c[/ITEM]"
  },
  {
    name: 'Item Two',
    desc: "Item 2 [ITEM:2]View 2[/ITEM] Item 2b [ITEM:2b]View 2b[/ITEM] Item 2c [ITEM:2c]View 2c[/ITEM]"
  },
  {
    name: 'Item three',
    desc: "Item 3 [ITEM:3]View 3[/ITEM] Item 3b [ITEM:3b]View 3b[/ITEM] Item 3c [ITEM:3c]View 1c[/ITEM]"
  }
```

And are then displayed using an ng-repeat like.

```
< div ng-repeat="item in items">
    < div class="col-sm-12" ng-bind-html="item.details | filter:search">< /div>
< /div>
```

Inside each is a block of text which potentially contains multiple strings from an old system that resemble the following.

```
[item:id]item name[/item]
```

How would I transform the json so that any instances of the above string could be intercepted and transformed into a clickable modal link such as

```
< a ng-click="viewItemDetails('1a');" >View 1a< /a >
```

I cannot change the structure of the text blocks.

**NOTE:** I have asked a similar question before and the suggestions neither worked nor were very graspable.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to pre process your data. 
Something like this: (I'll post a link to working code soon)

```
$scope.items.map(function(n) {
  var str = n.desc,
      re = /\[ITEM:.*?\]/ig,
      found = str.match(re);
  found = found.map(function(m) {
    return m.split(':')[1].replace(']', '');
  });

  return n.items = found;
});
```

and then use the new "items" property in a nested ng-repeat:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items" fixLinks>{{item.name}}
    <div>
      <span ng-repeat="n in item.items">
        Item {{n}} 
        <a href ng-click="viewItemDetails({{n}})">
          View {{n}}
        </a>&nbsp;
      </span>
    </div>
    <hr/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Here's the codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obdWXv)

**UPDATE**
Here's a [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZjQYg) that does the replacement:

```
$scope.items.map(function(n) {
  var str = n.desc,
      re = /\[ITEM:(.*?)\]/ig,
      tpl = '<a href ng-click="$1">'
  str = str.replace(re, tpl);
  str = str.replace(/\[\/ITEM\]/ig, '</a>');
  return n.muDesc = str;
});
```

**UPDATE #2** : Using directive, compiling and calling the controller scope method.
This can probably be improved but hopefully it helps for now. Here's the [updated pen](http://codepen.io/o4ohel/pen/BjxMgY)

Directive code:

```
app.directive('fixLinks', function ($parse, $compile) {
  function replaceStr(str) {
    var re = /\[ITEM:(.*?)\]/ig,
        tpl = '<a href ng-click="click(\'$1\')">'
    str = str.replace(re, tpl);
    str = str.replace(/\[\/ITEM\]/ig, '</a>');
    return str;
  }

  return {
    scope: {
      text: '=',
      flClick: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      var el = angular.element('<span>' + replaceStr(scope.text) + '</span>');
      $compile(el)(scope);
      element.append(el);
      scope.click = function(id) {
        scope.flClick({id: id});
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Markup:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div>{{item.name}}</div>
    <div fix-links text="item.desc" fl-click="viewItemDetails(id)"></div>
    <hr/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I cannot change the structure of the text so this would not work for me.

Comment: @freeBSD What do you mean by "structure of the text"?

Comment: There can be large blocks (sometimes three paragraphs) of text with these tags sprinkled throughout. I need to retain the formatting and just swap the tags with hyperlinks as they are found. (I updated the codepen to show a string of text.)

Comment: @freeBSD I've updated the answer twice assuming the last update is what would be most helpful for you.